# C++ Inheritance: arguments of derived class type in virtual function with base class types

Tags: c++, inheritance, design-patterns, abstract-class, virtual-functions

I'm having a rough time with a particular C++ inheritance problem. Say we have two abstract classes, one using the other as argument type for one of the pure virtual functions:

```cpp
class Food {
  public:
    int calories=0;
    virtual void set_calories(int cal)=0;
}

class Animal {
  public:
   int eaten_calories=0;
   virtual void eat_food(Food &f)=0;
}
```

Now, we create a derived class for each, **and we instantiate a virtual function with arguments of type the derived class**:

```cpp
class Vegetables: public Food{
  public:
   void set_calories(int cal){calories=cal;}
}
class Cow: public Animal{
  public:
   void eat_food(Vegetables &v){this->eaten_calories += v.calories;}
}
```

The problem with this is that the function `eat_food` requires a signature with the abstract class `Food`, or else a `Cow()` object creation won't compile, complaining that `Cow` is an abstract class because no suitable implementation of `eat_food(Food f)` was found.

***Update***: An additional constraint I seek for the implementation is that a second `class Meat: public Food` should not be usable with `Cow::eat_food(f)`. In short, just setting `Cow::eat_food(Food f)` and casting to `Vegetables` wouldn't cut it.

###### What is the best way to overcome this error?

So far I have found two options:

1. Creating an `eat_food(Food f)` implementation in `Cow` with a `try/catch` to check if `f` can be safely casted to `Vegetables`, and then calling `eat_food(Vegetables v)`. *PROBLEM*: if you have 50 virtual functions, this forces you to write 50 additional function implementations in `Cow`.
2. Turn the `Animal` into a Template class `Animal<T>`, and instantiate it with each of the derived classes of `Food` to define the animals (e.g., `class Cow: public Animal<Vegetables>`). *PROBLEM*: you can no longer define an `Animal*` pointer to hold an undefined animal with not known type.

Is there any viable/stylish alternative to these two? Maybe a software pattern of some kind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pass around a polymorphic type (like `Vegetables`) as a base type **by value** (like `Food f`), you will [slice the object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/), which prevents overriden methods from being called.

You need to pass such types **by pointer** or **by reference** instead, eg:

```cpp
class Food {
public:
    virtual int get_calories() const = 0;
};

class Animal {
public:
    int eaten_calories = 0;
    virtual void eat_food(Food& f) = 0;
};

class Vegetables: public Food {
public:
    int get_calories() const { return ...; }
};

class Cow: public Animal{
public:
    void eat_food(Food& f){ this->eaten_calories += f.get_calories(); }
};
```

```cpp
Vegetables veggies;
Cow cow;
cow.eat_food(veggies);
```

**UPDATE:**

You can't change the signature of a virtual method in derived classes (except when using covariant return types). Since `eat_food()` is exposed in `Animal` and takes a `Food&`, if you want `Cow::eat_food()` to accept only a `Vegetables` object and not a `Meat` object, then it needs to check at runtime if the input `Food&` refers to a `Vegetables` object and if not then throw an exception. `dynamic_cast` does exactly that for you when casting a reference, eg:

```cpp
class Cow: public Animal{
public:
    void eat_food(Food& f){ this->eaten_calories += dynamic_cast<Vegetables&>(f).calories; }
};
```

```cpp
Vegetables veggies;
Meat meat;
Cow cow;
cow.eat_food(veggies); // OK
cow.eat_food(meat); // throws std::bad_cast
```

Comment: Nice and clean answer... I just realized I missed out a limitation in my question! I'll update it now.

Comment: Done: In short, how should I do this so that `Cow` only eats `Vegetables`, and not, say, `class Meat: public Food`?

Comment: I also updated the question to pass arguments by reference (as it was the case in my actual code).

Comment: @ibarrond Covariance in virtual methods only works in return values, not parameters. I think your only option is to have `Cow::eat_food()` check if the input `Food` reference refers to a `Vegetables` object and if not then `throw` an exception. `dynamic_cast` does exactly that for you when casting a reference, eg: `void eat_food(Food &f){ this->eaten_calories += dynamic_cast<Vegetables&>(f).calories; }`

Comment: Nice! `dynamic_cast` is elegant and it provides a simple way to avoid duplicating function names. I'm gonna modify your answer with it

Comment: @ibarrond I rolled back your edit. The `dynamic_cast` is unnecessary in the example I gave in my answer, since `get_calories()` is exposed in `Food`. The `dynamic_cast` I showed in my earlier comment was in the context of your original code, not my answer.

Comment: Sure? I'd rather keep a final code snippet addressing the additional limitation.

Comment: @ibarrond I have updated my answer with another example

Answer (score 3):

When you defined the virtual function `Animal::eat_food()` accepting a `Food&` parameter, you declared that for any `Animal`, you can provide any `Food` to `eat_food()`. Now you want to break that promise. This brings into question your design. Either it is legitimate to call `ptr->eat_food(food)` where `ptr` is an `Animal*` and `food` is a `Meat`, or `eat_food()` should (probably) not be defined in the `Animal` class. If you cannot substitute one `Food` for another, use of `Food&` is likely a mistake. If you cannot substitute one `Animal` for another, defining at the `Animal` level is likely a mistake.

Perhaps a small change in nomenclature would help this make more sense. Consider renaming `eat_food` to `give_food`, or perhaps `feed`. Now you have a concept that is applicable to all animals. You can feed any food to any animal, but whether or not the animal eats it is a different story. Maybe you should make your virtual function `feed()` so that it applies equally well to all animals. If you have an `Animal*` and a `Food&`, you can feed the animal, but it's the animal that decides if it eats. If you were to instead insist that you must know the correct type of `Food` before feeding the `Animal`, then you should have a `Cow*` instead of an `Animal*`.

*Note:* If you happen to be in a case where you never try to feed an `Animal*`, then you could remove the virtual function from `Animal`, in which case your question becomes moot.

This might look something like the following.

```cpp
class Animal {
    int eaten_calories=0;
  protected:
    void eat_food(Food &f) { eaten_calories += f.calories; }  // Not virtual
  public:
    virtual void feed(Food &f)=0;
};

class Cow: public Animal{
  public:
    void feed(Food &f) override {
        // Cows only eat Vegetables.
        if ( dynamic_cast<Vegetables*>(&f) ) // if `f` is a Vegetables
            eat_food(f);
        else
            stampede(); // Or whatever you think is amusing (or appropriate).
    }
};
```

Note that I have kept your `eat_food()` implementation, but moved it to a non-virtual function in `Animal`. This is based on an assumption, so it might be inappropriate. However, I am willing to assume that no matter what type of animal, and no matter what type of food, if the animal actually eats the food, then the eaten calories should increase by the food's calories.

In addition, a rule of thumb says that this might be the correct level of abstraction -- the two bits of data being used, `calories` and `eaten_calories`, belong directly to the two classes being used, `Animal` and `Food`. This suggests (just a rule of thumb) that your logic and data are at a consistent level of abstraction.

Oh, I also specified `protected` access for `eat_food()`. This way it is the object's decision whether or not to eat. No one will be able to force an animal to eat; they would only be able to offer it food. This demonstrates another principle of polymorphic design: when derived classes differ, only the objects of those classes should need to be aware of those differences. Code that sees only objects of a common base should not need to test for these differences in advance of using those objects.

Comment: You surely took the Animals and Food example far! Thanks for the suggestions.